# How to achieve this route?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to achieve the route "  /stock/{{stock->id}}/quantity  ".
So i have created a folder named "quantity" inside resources/views/stocks/ .
And i have also created an index.blade.php file inside quantity.

"  /stock/{{stock->id}}  "shows the details of the stock i.e "show.blade.php"

Inside "show.blade.php" i have placed the link to my quantity page. Given Below is the code.

```
<a href="/stocks/{{$stock->id}}/quantity">Quantity</a>
```

But its not working. Am i doing correct?

I did add Route::resource('quantity', 'QuanityController'); to web.php Please help someone!
This is my controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Quanity;
use App\Stock;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class QuanityController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {       
        return view('quanity.index');            
    }

}
```

Comment: ohhh i just created for my convenience. Because a lot of folders are to come. I just want to achieve the route can u help me?

Comment: What's the error? is there any error while using the url?

Comment: U misspelled `quantity` with `quanity` xD

Comment: it worked now Thanks :D!!!

Comment: Now i want to add a condition ! Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should user route name in web.php don't use $ sign in parameter route use like this.
it is good to give different name to every route for  its unique identification.

```
Route::get('/stocks/{stock_id}/quantity','QuanityController @index')->name('stock.quantity');
```

In blade use route name and pass parameter like this:-

```
 <a href="{{ route('stock.quantity',$stock->id) }}">Quantity</a>
```

In Controller Recieve that parameter:-

```
class QuanityController extends Controller
{

   public function index($stock_id)
   {       
       return view('quanity.index');            
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I will try and get back to you :)

Comment: Hey it shows sorry this page could not be found! It seems something wrong with route

Comment: 'Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('stocks', 'StockController');
    Route::get('/stocks/{stock->id}/quantity','QuantityController@index')->name('stock.quantity');
}

Comment: sorry change route to this :-

Comment: Route::get('/stocks/{stock_id}/quantity','QuantityController @index')->name('stock.quantity'); });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176961/discussion-between-devender-gupta-and-arslan-akram).